# How do I get the number of Items in a recyclerView using firebase data?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I create a RecyclerView with a series of CardViews inside. My end goal is being able to change the text inside of an individual CardView in the activity due to the timing of firebase database calls. My question right now is how does one get the number of items in the RecyclerView?

I know that most will reference me to the Adapter.getItemCount() method. However, at the moment that is only returning zero as the adapter seems to have not been created yet. I believe that this question is more along the lines of the timings of when code runs.

The activity class:

```java
package com.cmsc355.forfit;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.cmsc355.forfit.util.exerciseAdapterClass;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class ChallengeView extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static Context context;
    public static String cCESnapshot;

    //Variables
    String team;
    HashMap<String, String> currChallenges;
    ArrayList<String> subAthletes;
    ArrayList<String> exerciseList;
    ArrayList<String> teamMem;

    //System
    private Intent intent;
    public static String cName;

    //XML
    private TextView name;
    private TextView startDateTV;
    private TextView endDateTV;
    private TextView description;
    private Button bSubscribe;
    private Button bDropout;

    private ProgressBar difficulty;

    //Exercise List
    private RecyclerView exerciseRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter exerciseAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager exerciselayoutManager;

    //Database
    DatabaseReference databaseReferenceChallenge;
    DatabaseReference databaseReferenceAthlete;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Initial setup of activity
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_challenge_view);

        ChallengeView.context = getApplicationContext();

        //variable list
        currChallenges = new HashMap<>();
        subAthletes = new ArrayList<>();
        exerciseList = new ArrayList<>();
        teamMem = new ArrayList<>();

        //system references
        intent = getIntent();
        cName = intent.getStringExtra("name");
        //cCESnapshot = intent.getStringExtra("snapshot");
        //System.out.println(cCESnapshot);

        //Authentication references
        FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        final String uid = user.getUid();

        //XML references
        name = findViewById(R.id.ChallengeName);
        startDateTV = findViewById(R.id.DurationTextStart);
        endDateTV = findViewById(R.id.DurationTextEnd);
        description = findViewById(R.id.DescriptionText);
        difficulty = findViewById(R.id.difficultyBar);

        bSubscribe = findViewById(R.id.BSignUp);
        bDropout = findViewById(R.id.CV_DropOut);

        //Exercise List
        exerciseRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.ExerciseView);
        exerciseRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        exerciselayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        exerciseRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(exerciselayoutManager);

        exerciseAdapter = new exerciseAdapterClass(exerciseList);
        exerciseRecyclerView.setAdapter(exerciseAdapter);
        exerciseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        //database references
        databaseReferenceChallenge = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Challenges");
        databaseReferenceAthlete = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Athlete Users");



        //Initial population of views and variables
        databaseReferenceChallenge.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                DataSnapshot da = dataSnapshot.child(cName);

                String dateStart = da.child("StartDate").child("day").getValue() + "/" + da.child("StartDate").child("month").getValue()+ "/" + da.child("StartDate").child("year").getValue();
                String dateEnd = da.child("EndDate").child("day").getValue() + "/" + da.child("EndDate").child("month").getValue()+ "/" + da.child("EndDate").child("year").getValue();


                long diff = (long)da.child("difficulty").getValue();
                int tDifficulty = (int)diff;

                name.setText((String)da.child("name").getValue());
                startDateTV.setText(dateStart);
                endDateTV.setText(dateEnd);
                description.setText((String)da.child("description").getValue());
                difficulty.setMin(1);
                difficulty.setMax(5);
                difficulty.setProgress(tDifficulty);


                for(DataSnapshot ex : da.child("exercises").getChildren()){
                    exerciseList.add((String)ex.getValue());
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        //***************************************************************************************************************************************\\
        //This should be grabbing all the challenges that the athlete is currently subscribed to.
        databaseReferenceAthlete.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 = dataSnapshot.child(uid).child("currChallenges");
                HashMap<String, String> currChallengesT = (HashMap<String, String>) dataSnapshot1.getValue();
                currChallenges.clear();
                if(currChallengesT != null) {
                    currChallenges.putAll(currChallengesT);
                    if(currChallenges.containsKey(cName)) {
                        bSubscribe.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        bDropout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    else{
                        bSubscribe.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        bDropout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    bSubscribe.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    bDropout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        });
        //***************************************************************************************************************************************\\

        //***************************************************************************************************************************************\\
        //This should be grabbing all the athletes subscribed to the challenge.
        databaseReferenceChallenge.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 = dataSnapshot.child(cName).child("subscribedAthletes");
                ArrayList<String> subAthletesT = (ArrayList<String>) dataSnapshot1.getValue();
                if(subAthletesT != null) {
                    subAthletes.addAll(subAthletesT);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        });
        //***************************************************************************************************************************************\\

        databaseReferenceAthlete.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 = dataSnapshot.child(uid).child("currChallenges").child(cName).child("team");
                team = (String) dataSnapshot1.getValue();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();


        //This is where I try to call the Recycler View.

        System.out.println(exerciseList.size());

        for(int i = 0; i < exerciseAdapter.getItemCount(); i ++){
            System.out.println("Inside for loop: " + i);
            CardView thing = (CardView) exerciselayoutManager.getChildAt(i);
            exerciseAdapterClass.exerciseViewHolder holder = (exerciseAdapterClass.exerciseViewHolder) exerciseRecyclerView.getChildViewHolder(thing);
            System.out.println("\n\n==============================================================\n" + holder.amount.getText().toString() +
                    "\n==============================================================");
        }

    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return ChallengeView.context;
    }

    /*
    Calls for the transfer to the challenge signup activity
     */
    public void Subscribe(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent (this, ChallengeSignUp.class);
        intent.putExtra("name", cName);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

The Adapter Class:

```java
package com.cmsc355.forfit.util;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.cmsc355.forfit.ChallengeView;
import com.cmsc355.forfit.R;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class exerciseAdapterClass extends RecyclerView.Adapter<exerciseAdapterClass.exerciseViewHolder>{

    ArrayList<String> exerciseList;

    public static class exerciseViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public CardView cardView;
        public TextView exerciseName;
        public TextView amount;
        public EditText inputAmount;
        public Button bEnter;

        DatabaseReference databaseReferenceChallenge;
        DatabaseReference databaseReferenceAthlete;

        int currDone;



        public exerciseViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            //Variables
            currDone = 0;

            //Authentication
            FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
            final String uid = user.getUid();

            //Database Reference
            databaseReferenceChallenge = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Challenges");
            databaseReferenceAthlete = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Athlete Users");

            //XML
            cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv_cardView);
            exerciseName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv_exerciseName);
            amount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv_amount);
            inputAmount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv_input);
            bEnter = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv_button);

            bEnter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(!(inputAmount.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0)){
                        int input = Integer.parseInt(inputAmount.getText().toString());
                        final String cName = ChallengeView.cName;

                        databaseReferenceAthlete.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                try{
                                    DataSnapshot snapshot = dataSnapshot.child(uid).child("currChallenges").child(cName).child(exerciseName.getText().toString());
                                    currDone = (int)((long)snapshot.getValue());
                                }
                                catch(Exception e){
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
                        });

                        currDone += input;
                        databaseReferenceAthlete.child(uid).child("currChallenges").child(cName).child(exerciseName.getText().toString()).setValue(currDone);

                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(ChallengeView.getAppContext(), "Nothing in there.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public exerciseAdapterClass(ArrayList<String> inputList){
        exerciseList = inputList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return exerciseList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public exerciseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cv_card, viewGroup, false);
        exerciseViewHolder pvh = new exerciseViewHolder(v);
        return pvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final exerciseViewHolder holder, final int i) {
        holder.setIsRecyclable(false);

        String s1 = exerciseList.get(i);

        //Possible error if the name contains "Amount"
        final String name = s1.substring(0, s1.indexOf("Amount")-1); //first section of the string to give the name.

        String s2 = s1.substring(s1.indexOf(": ")); //cuts of the front of the string and puts to a new substring.

        String a = s2.substring(s2.indexOf(' '), s2.indexOf("\n")); //cuts the part after the : but before the \n
        a = a.trim(); //trims the inevitable white space
        final String units = a.substring(a.indexOf(' ')); //gets the units off the string
        a = a.substring(0, a.indexOf(' ')); //cuts off the units
        final int amount = Integer.parseInt(a); //parse to use as a number

        String s3 = s2.substring(s2.indexOf("\n")); //cuts to the date and new string
        s3 = s3.substring(8); //removes the date tag

        String y = s3.substring(0, s3.indexOf('/')); //cuts year into new string
        final int year = Integer.parseInt(y); //parse year to use as a number

        s3 = s3.substring(s3.indexOf('/') + 1); //cuts year off

        String d = s3.substring(0, s3.indexOf('/')); //cuts day into new string
        final int day = Integer.parseInt(d); //parse day

        s3 = s3.substring(s3.indexOf('/') + 1); //cuts day off
        final int month = Integer.parseInt(s3); //parses month

        /*DatabaseReference databaseReferenceAthlete = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Athlete Users");
        databaseReferenceAthlete.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
            final String uid = user.getUid();

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                DataSnapshot snapshot = dataSnapshot.child(uid).child("currChallenges").child(ChallengeView.cName).child(name);
                try{
                    int val = ((int)((long)snapshot.getValue()));


                    int printVal = Math.max(0, amount - val);



                }
                catch(Exception e){}
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });*/
        holder.amount.setText("0" + units);
        holder.exerciseName.setText(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }
}
```

As of right now, when I try to call for anything referencing the RecyclerView, it returns either 0 or null. My thought is that the code to instate the RecyclerView has not been run yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have done is:
In the adapter class, you are trying to retrieve the firebase data.
By the time it returns data the constructor is being called, and where the size of the list `exerciseList` is zero. And another thing to notice is you have mentioned firebase call (Which operates in the background) in `ViewHolder` class.

The best way to do this is:
First, you get the data from firebase outside the adapter and then set adapter. Like
In `MainActivity` do the background job (to retrieve data from Firebase ) and then after successfully retrieve, set adapter like

```
exerciseAdapterClass adapter = new Adapter (exerciseList);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

If you want to notify the recycler view if there are some changes occurred in firebase data you can do that as below:

Get the changed list (`exerciseList`) Or changed item(`String`) from the firebase using

```
databaseReferenceAthlete.addValueEventListener
```

Or

```
databaseReferenceAthlete.addChildEventListener
```

and then

```
adapter.update(exerciseList);
adapter.notifyDatasetChanged;
```

Or

```
adapter.update(newString);
adapter.notifyItemChanged(position)
```

***Note: you have to set up the update method in adapter class**

Example:
Adapter to update list

```
public class NoteListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NoteListAdapter.NoteViewHolder> {

private List<String> list;

public NoteListAdapter(List<String> list) {
    this.list = list;
}

public void update(List<String> list){
    this.list = list;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public NoteViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
    Context context = parent.getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View noteView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_note, parent, false);

    return new NoteViewHolder(noteView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NoteViewHolder holder, int i) {
    String itemString = list.get(i);
    holder.textView.setText(itemString);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public class NoteViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private TextView textView;

    public NoteViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_rv);
    }
}
}
```

in mainActivity:

```
public class NotesActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NotesContract.View{

private TextView textView;
private Button add;
private NotesContract.UserActionsListener mActionsListener;
private NoteRepository repository;

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private NoteListAdapter adapter;
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    add = findViewById(R.id.button);
    repository = new NoteRepository();
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    adapter = new NoteListAdapter(list);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);



    mActionsListener = new NotePresenter(repository,this);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            mActionsListener.loadNotes("hello");
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void showAddNote(List<String> data) {
    String line = "";
    for(String s:data){
        line = line.concat(s);

    }
    textView.setText(line);
}

@Override
public void showRecViewNote(List<String> data) {
    adapter.update(data);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


}
}
```

Look at, how the recycler view got set

```
recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    adapter = new NoteListAdapter(list);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and how it is notified

```
public void showRecViewNote(List<String> data) {
    adapter.update(data);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


}
```

Comment: The only place I call firebase from in the adapter is in the onButtonClick. Although this could help with a different problem. However, how is it that I setup the "update" function? As of right now, all I do is update the ArrayList<String>. Is there any way to call the methods again?

Comment: in onBindViewHolder method of the adapter class, you can call firebase like holder.button.setOnClickListner() as well. In the Adapter Class mention a method update(exerciseList) and there you can swap the old list with new list.

Comment: Pretty sure you are referring to the commented out bit of code. I left it there so I don't need to rethink my way through the call. It does not get run.